# I've cloned a lot of github repos. Looking for a readme.md viewer

Tags: git, github

Is there any way to view a formatted readme.md file apart from opening the repo on the web?

Comment: The Atom editor can render markdown locally.

Comment: export html option from [grip](https://github.com/joeyespo/grip) solves the problem.